# Calculating Integrals with infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to calculate this integral :
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}{e}^{-\left(\mathrm{i}w+2\right)t} dt
$$
Without using the limits => $\int f(t)dt$, I got this result below :

$\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\mathrm{i}w+2\right)t}}{-\mathrm{i}w-2} + C$

So to calculate the integral in this interval : $[0,+\infty]$ I just have to calculate the limit for this function $\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\mathrm{i}w+2\right)t}}{-\mathrm{i}w-2} + C$
in $0$ and $+\infty$ .
My question is how do we calculate the limit of such function in $+\infty$ .

Comment: You might want to change $dx$ to $dt$.

Comment: Wups yeah sorry

Comment: HInt: $|e^{it}| = 1$

Comment: What is $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-2t}$?

Comment: $e^{-t}=0$ at $t= \infty$, so the term cancels also $C's$ cancel each other at the ends.

Comment: oh yeah  $lim→∞e^{−2t} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $w$ is real (which you didn't say),
$$
\left|e^{-(iw+2)t}\right| = e^{-2t}
$$
This goes to $0$ much more rapidly than any polynomial, so the limit at $t=\infty$ is $0$.